# ¿Cómo hacer un algoritmo para encontrar números perfectos?

Tags: algoritmos, while

Necesito crear un algoritmo que me muestre los primeros 10 números perfectos pero estoy cometiendo un error que no logro identificar porque solo me imprime los primeros 3 y la ejecución no finaliza...

Algoritmo problema2

```
Definir n,d,x,perfecto Como Real
n <- 2

Mientras x<=10 Hacer
    perfecto <- 0

    Para d<-1 Hasta (n/2) Hacer
        Si n MOD d=0 Entonces
            perfecto <- perfecto+d
        FinSi
    FinPara

    Si perfecto==n Entonces
        Escribir perfecto
        x <- x+1
    FinSi

    n <- n+1

FinMientras
```

FinAlgoritmo

[image: Este es el algoritmo]

Comment: Puedes copiar y pegar el código en tu pregunta. No se visualiza la imagen.

Comment: Hola @ed bienvenidx a la comunidad, parece que tu pregunta no está en lo mejor de tus capacidades, recuerda siempre ofrecer un buen contexto, con material de apoyo, como código e imágenes y que esté acompañada con tu mejor habilidad de redacción, te invito a leer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que te nutras sobre como usar stack a tu favor, de lo contrario podría afectar tu reputación en el futuro, no te desanimes, te invito a editar tu pregunta, un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tu algoritmo esta bien pero necesitas una gran capacidad computacional para encontrar los 10 primeros nùmeros primos ya que si bien el primero es 6 el el decimo es 
191561942…548169216, que es un numero muy grande lo cual necesitara una cantidad grande de iteraciones, es la razon por la cual solo muestra los tres primeros y no finaliza.

Puedes usar la formular que se describe [en este enlace](http://www.vaxasoftware.com/doc_edu/mat/numperfe_esp.pdf).